# How do I replace Quantstrat 'for loop' with mclapply [parallelized]?

Tags: r, parallel-processing, quantstrat, mclapply

I'd like to parallelize quantstrat.  My code isn't exactly like this, but this showcases the issue.  The problem I believe is the .blotter env is initialized to a pointer memory address and i am unable to initialize an array/matrix of new.env().

What I would like to do is replace the for loop with an mclapply so I can run multiple applyStrategies with varying dates/symbols (only varying symbols is shown here).  My end goal is a beowulf cluster (makeCluster) and plan on running these in parallel using up to 252 trading days (rolling window) with varying symbols per iteration (but I don't need all that.  I simply am asking if there is a way to work with assigning portfolio and the subsequent .blotter memory object in such a way where I can use mclapply)

```
#Load quantstrat in your R environment.

rm(list = ls())

local()

library(quantstrat) 
library(parallel)

# The search command lists all attached packages.
search()

symbolstring1 <- c('QQQ','GOOG')
#symbolstring <- c('QQQ','GOOG')

#for(i in 1:length(symbolstring1))
  mlapply(symbolstring1, function(symbolstring)
{
  #local()
  #i=2
  #symbolstring=as.character(symbolstring1[i])
  
  .blotter <- new.env()
  .strategy <- new.env()
  
  try(rm.strat(strategyName),silent=TRUE)
  try(rm(envir=FinancialInstrument:::.instrument),silent=TRUE)
  for (name in ls(FinancialInstrument:::.instrument)){rm_instruments(name,keep.currencies = FALSE)}
  print(symbolstring)

currency('USD')

stock(symbolstring,currency='USD',multiplier=1)

# Currency and trading instrument objects stored in the 
# .instrument environment

print("FI")
ls(envir=FinancialInstrument:::.instrument)

# blotter functions used for instrument initialization 
# quantstrat creates a private storage area called .strategy

ls(all=T)

# The initDate should be lower than the startDate. The initDate will be used later while initializing the strategy.

initDate <- '2010-01-01'

startDate <- '2011-01-01'

endDate <- '2019-08-10'

init_equity <- 50000

# Set UTC TIME

Sys.setenv(TZ="UTC")

getSymbols(symbolstring,from=startDate,to=endDate,adjust=TRUE,src='yahoo')

# Define names for portfolio, account and strategy. 

#portfolioName <- accountName <- strategyName <- "FirstPortfolio"
portfolioName <- accountName <- strategyName <- paste0("FirstPortfolio",symbolstring)

print(portfolioName)
# The function rm.strat removes any strategy, portfolio, account, or order book object with the given name. This is important

#rm.strat(strategyName)

print("port")
initPortf(name = portfolioName,
          symbols = symbolstring,
          initDate = initDate)

initAcct(name = accountName,
         portfolios = portfolioName,
         initDate = initDate,
         initEq = init_equity)

initOrders(portfolio = portfolioName,
           symbols = symbolstring,
           initDate = initDate)



# name: the string name of the strategy

# assets: optional list of assets to apply the strategy to.  

# Normally these are defined in the portfolio object

# contstrains: optional portfolio constraints

# store: can be True or False. If True store the strategy in the environment. Default is False
print("strat")
strategy(strategyName, store = TRUE)

ls(all=T)

# .blotter holds the portfolio and account object 

ls(.blotter)

# .strategy holds the orderbook and strategy object

print(ls(.strategy))

print("ind")
add.indicator(strategy = strategyName, 
              name = "EMA", 
              arguments = list(x = quote(Cl(mktdata)), 
                               n = 10), label = "nFast")

add.indicator(strategy = strategyName, 
              name = "EMA", 
              arguments = list(x = quote(Cl(mktdata)), 
                               n = 30), 
              label = "nSlow")

# Add long signal when the fast EMA crosses over slow EMA.

print("sig")
add.signal(strategy = strategyName,
           name="sigCrossover",
           arguments = list(columns = c("nFast", "nSlow"),
                            relationship = "gte"),
           label = "longSignal")

# Add short signal when the fast EMA goes below slow EMA.

add.signal(strategy = strategyName, 
           name = "sigCrossover",
           arguments = list(columns = c("nFast", "nSlow"),
                            relationship = "lt"),
           label = "shortSignal")

# go long when 10-period EMA (nFast) >= 30-period EMA (nSlow)

print("rul")
add.rule(strategyName,
         name= "ruleSignal",
         arguments=list(sigcol="longSignal",
                        sigval=TRUE,
                        orderqty=100,
                        ordertype="market",
                        orderside="long",
                        replace = TRUE, 
                        TxnFees = -10),
         type="enter",
         label="EnterLong") 

# go short when 10-period EMA (nFast) < 30-period EMA (nSlow)

add.rule(strategyName, 
         name = "ruleSignal", 
         arguments = list(sigcol = "shortSignal", 
                          sigval = TRUE, 
                          orderside = "short", 
                          ordertype = "market", 
                          orderqty = -100, 
                          TxnFees = -10,                     
                          replace = TRUE), 
         type = "enter", 
         label = "EnterShort")

# Close long positions when the shortSignal column is True

add.rule(strategyName, 
         name = "ruleSignal", 
         arguments = list(sigcol = "shortSignal", 
                          sigval = TRUE, 
                          orderside = "long", 
                          ordertype = "market", 
                          orderqty = "all", 
                          TxnFees = -10, 
                          replace = TRUE), 
         type = "exit", 
         label = "ExitLong")

# Close Short positions when the longSignal column is True

add.rule(strategyName, 
         name = "ruleSignal", 
         arguments = list(sigcol = "longSignal", 
                          sigval = TRUE, 
                          orderside = "short", 
                          ordertype = "market", 
                          orderqty = "all", 
                          TxnFees = -10, 
                          replace = TRUE), 
         type = "exit", 
         label = "ExitShort")

print("summary")
summary(getStrategy(strategyName))

# Summary results are produced below

print("results")
results <- applyStrategy(strategy= strategyName, portfolios = portfolioName,symbols=symbolstring)

# The applyStrategy() outputs all transactions(from the oldest to recent transactions)that the strategy sends. The first few rows of the applyStrategy() output are shown below

getTxns(Portfolio=portfolioName, Symbol=symbolstring)

mktdata

updatePortf(portfolioName)

dateRange <- time(getPortfolio(portfolioName)$summary)[-1]

updateAcct(portfolioName,dateRange)

updateEndEq(accountName)

print(plot(tail(getAccount(portfolioName)$summary$End.Eq,-1), main = "Portfolio Equity"))

#cleanup
for (name in symbolstring) rm(list = name)
#rm(.blotter)
rm(.stoploss)
rm(.txnfees)
#rm(.strategy)
rm(symbols)

}
)
```

But an error is thrown
Error in get(symbol, envir = envir) : object 'QQQ' not found

Specifically the problem is FinancialInstrument:::.instrument is pointing to a memory address that isn't updated with my encapsulated variable calls (symbolstring)

Comment: Not sure where and how parallelization is happening in your code example, if you're in control, try with [**future.apply**](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/future.apply/).

Answer (score 3):

`apply.paramset` in `quantstrat` already uses a `foreach` construct to parallelize execution of `applyStrategy`.

`apply.paramset` needs to do a fair amount of work to make sure that the environments are available in the workers to do the work, and to collect the proper results to send them back to the calling process.

The simplest thing for you to do would probably be to use `apply.paramset`.  Make your dates and symbols parameters, and have the function run normally.

Alternately, I suggest you look at the steps required to use a parallel `foreach` construction in `apply.paramset` to modify it to your suggested case.

Also note that your question asks about using a Beowulf cluster and `mclapply`.  This won't work.  `mclapply` only works in a single memory space.  Beowulf clusters don't normally share a single memory and process space. They typically distribute jobs via parallel libraries such as MPI.  `apply.paramset` could already distribute on a Beowulf cluster by using a `doMPI` backend to `foreach`.  That is one of the reasons we used `foreach`: the multitude of different parallel backends that are available. The `doMC` backend for `foreach` actually uses `mclapply` behind the scenes.

Comment: This doesn't exactly answer the problem.  I was able to get mclapply to work (and about to answer my own question).  I clarified my question wasn't "how to do beowulf". Merely that's an end goal.  Currently I'd like to get mclapply to work.  So far moving the stock objects outside the loop seems to work.  The correct function to use with makeCluster is clusterApply[LB].  As to paramset.  My understanding is it varies certain parm's in signals, not necessarily stocks and dates, but I could be wrong.  If your answer gave an example using the code above using paramset I might mark it "answered"

Comment: I take it back.  Putting the stock objects outside mclapply creates a date issue.  Quantstrat loads whatever dates are in the object.  The only way to iterate over different dates is to remove the object and repopulate with different dates.  So the problem seems to be shared memory of object names

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I'm going to digest this "The simplest thing for you to do would probably be to use apply.paramset. Make your dates and symbols parameters, and have the function run normally."

Comment: My apologies Brian.  I was completely unaware I was speaking with the author of the tool I was asking questions about.  I am still trying to wrap my head around how to use paramset

Comment: I see mclapply and any mc package is "readonly" and cannot update shared memory variables, which is part of the learning curve I'm dealing with.

Comment: I found a solution for dates.  Most of the functions have a Dates=. So I can generate my list of symbols ahead of time as well as Dates in a separate loop, then pass those in as paramsets.  I think that's the only way I can do it properly.  I see this problem is going to take more out of the box thinking than I'm used to for the beowulf bit.

Comment: apply.paramset(strategyName,
                 paramset.label = "symbolSet",
                 portfolio.st = strategyName,
                 account.st = strategyName, 
                 paramsets = list(symbolstring=symbolstring1[1],
                                 symbolstring=symbolstring1[2],
                                 symbolstring=symbolstring1[3]),
                 nsamples = 0)
which expects a add.distribution?  which has component.type which I'm unsure what to set to

Answer (score 1):

I believe this parallelizes the code.  I've swapped the indicators out as well as as symbols, but the logic of using different symbols and dates is in there

Basically I added

`Dates=paste0(startDate,"::",endDate)`

```
rm(list = ls())

library(lubridate)
library(parallel)

autoregressor1  = function(x){
  if(NROW(x)<12){ result = NA} else{
    y = Vo(x)*Ad(x)
    #y = ROC(Ad(x))
    y = ROC(y)
    y = na.omit(y)
    step1 = ar.yw(y)
    step2 = predict(step1,newdata=y,n.ahead=1)
    step3 = step2$pred[1]+1
    step4 = (step3*last(Ad(x))) - last(Ad(x))
    
    result = step4
  }
  return(result)
}

autoregressor = function(x){
  ans = rollapply(x,26,FUN = autoregressor1,by.column=FALSE)
  return (ans)}

########################indicators#############################

library(quantstrat) 
library(future.apply)
library(scorecard)

reset_quantstrat <- function() {
  if (! exists(".strategy")) .strategy <<- new.env(parent = .GlobalEnv)
  if (! exists(".blotter")) .blotter <<- new.env(parent = .GlobalEnv)
  if (! exists(".audit")) .audit <<- new.env(parent = .GlobalEnv)
  suppressWarnings(rm(list = ls(.strategy), pos = .strategy))
  suppressWarnings(rm(list = ls(.blotter), pos = .blotter))
  suppressWarnings(rm(list = ls(.audit), pos = .audit))
  FinancialInstrument::currency("USD")
}

reset_quantstrat()

initDate <- '2010-01-01'

endDate <- as.Date(Sys.Date())
startDate <- endDate %m-% years(3)

symbolstring1 <- c('SSO','GOLD')

getSymbols(symbolstring1,from=startDate,to=endDate,adjust=TRUE,src='yahoo')

#symbolstring1 <- c('SP500TR','GOOG')

.orderqty <- 1
.txnfees <- 0

#random <- sample(1:2, 2, replace=FALSE)

random <- (1:2)

equity <- lapply(random, function(x)
{#x=1
  try(rm("account.Snazzy","portfolio.Snazzy",pos=.GlobalEnv$.blotter),silent=TRUE)
  rm(.blotter)
  rm(.strategy)
  portfolioName <- accountName <- strategyName <- paste0("FirstPortfolio",x+2)
  #endDate <- as.Date(Sys.Date())
  startDate <- endDate %m-% years(1+x)
 
  #Load quantstrat in your R environment.
  reset_quantstrat()
  
  # The search command lists all attached packages.
  search()

  symbolstring=as.character(symbolstring1[x])
  print(symbolstring)
  
  try(rm.strat(strategyName),silent=TRUE)
  try(rm(envir=FinancialInstrument:::.instrument),silent=TRUE)
  for (name in ls(FinancialInstrument:::.instrument)){rm_instruments(name,keep.currencies = FALSE)}
  print(symbolstring)
  
  currency('USD')
  
  stock(symbolstring,currency='USD',multiplier=1)
  
  # Currency and trading instrument objects stored in the 
  # .instrument environment
  
  print("FI")
  ls(envir=FinancialInstrument:::.instrument)
  
  # blotter functions used for instrument initialization 
  # quantstrat creates a private storage area called .strategy
  
  ls(all=T)
  
  init_equity <- 10000
  
  Sys.setenv(TZ="UTC")
  
  print(portfolioName)
 
  print("port")

  try(initPortf(name = portfolioName,
            symbols = symbolstring,
            initDate = initDate))
  
 
  try(initAcct(name = accountName,
           portfolios = portfolioName,
           initDate = initDate,
           initEq = init_equity))
  
  try(initOrders(portfolio = portfolioName,
             symbols = symbolstring,
             initDate = initDate))
  
  # name: the string name of the strategy
  
  # assets: optional list of assets to apply the strategy to.  
  
  # Normally these are defined in the portfolio object
  
  # contstrains: optional portfolio constraints
  
  # store: can be True or False. If True store the strategy in the environment. Default is False
  print("strat")
  strategy(strategyName, store = TRUE)
  
  ls(all=T)
  
  # .blotter holds the portfolio and account object 
  
  ls(.blotter)
  
  # .strategy holds the orderbook and strategy object
  
  print(ls(.strategy))
  
  print("ind")
  #ARIMA
    
    add.indicator(
      strategy  =   strategyName, 
      name      =   "autoregressor", 
      arguments =   list(
        x       =   quote(mktdata)),
      label     =   "arspread")
    
    ################################################ Signals #############################
    
    add.signal(
      strategy          = strategyName,
      name              = "sigThreshold",
      arguments         = list(
        threshold       = 0.25,
        column          = "arspread",
        relationship    = "gte",
        cross           = TRUE),
      label             = "Selltime")
    
    add.signal(
      strategy          = strategyName,
      name              = "sigThreshold",
      arguments         = list(
        threshold       = 0.1,
        column          = "arspread",
        relationship    = "lt",
        cross           = TRUE),
      label             = "cashtime")
    
    add.signal(
      strategy          = strategyName,
      name              = "sigThreshold",
      arguments         = list(
        threshold       = -0.1,
        column          = "arspread",
        relationship    = "gt",
        cross           = TRUE),
      label             = "cashtime")
    
    add.signal(
      strategy          = strategyName,
      name              = "sigThreshold",
      arguments         = list(
        threshold       = -0.25,
        column          = "arspread",
        relationship    = "lte",
        cross           = TRUE),
      label             = "Buytime")
    
    ######################################## Rules #################################################
    
    #Entry Rule Long
    add.rule(strategyName,
             name               =   "ruleSignal",
             arguments          =   list(
               sigcol           =   "Buytime",
               sigval           =   TRUE,
               orderqty     =   .orderqty,
               ordertype        =   "market",
               orderside        =   "long",
               pricemethod      =   "market",
               replace          =   TRUE,
               TxnFees              =   -.txnfees
               #,
               #osFUN               =   osMaxPos
             ), 
             type               =   "enter",
             path.dep           =   TRUE,
             label              =   "Entry")
    
    #Entry Rule Short
    
    add.rule(strategyName,
             name           =   "ruleSignal",
             arguments          =   list(
               sigcol           =   "Selltime",
               sigval           =   TRUE,
               orderqty     =   .orderqty,
               ordertype        =   "market",
               orderside        =   "short",
               pricemethod      =   "market",
               replace          =   TRUE,
               TxnFees              =   -.txnfees
               #,
               #osFUN               =   osMaxPos
             ), 
             type               =   "enter",
             path.dep           =   TRUE,
             label              =   "Entry")
    
    #Exit Rules
    
  print("summary")
  summary(getStrategy(strategyName))
  
  # Summary results are produced below
  
  print("results")
  
  results <- applyStrategy(strategy= strategyName, portfolios = portfolioName)
  
  # The applyStrategy() outputs all transactions(from the oldest to recent transactions)that the strategy sends. The first few rows of the applyStrategy() output are shown below
  
  getTxns(Portfolio=portfolioName, Symbol=symbolstring)
  
  mktdata
  
  updatePortf(portfolioName,Dates=paste0(startDate,"::",endDate))
  
  dateRange <- time(getPortfolio(portfolioName)$summary)
  
  updateAcct(portfolioName,dateRange[which(dateRange >= startDate & dateRange <= endDate)])
  
  updateEndEq(accountName, Dates=paste0(startDate,"::",endDate))
  
  print(plot(tail(getAccount(portfolioName)$summary$End.Eq,-1), main = symbolstring))
  
  tStats <- tradeStats(Portfolios = portfolioName, use="trades", inclZeroDays=FALSE,Dates=paste0(startDate,"::",endDate))
  
  final_acct <- getAccount(portfolioName)
  
  #final_acct
  #View(final_acct)
  
  options(width=70)
  
  print(plot(tail(final_acct$summary$End.Eq,-1), main = symbolstring))
  #dev.off()
  
  tail(final_acct$summary$End.Eq)
  
  rets <- PortfReturns(Account = accountName)
  
  #rownames(rets) <- NULL
  
  tab.perf <- table.Arbitrary(rets,
                              metrics=c(
                                "Return.cumulative",
                                "Return.annualized",
                                "SharpeRatio.annualized",
                                "CalmarRatio"),
                              metricsNames=c(
                                "Cumulative Return",
                                "Annualized Return",
                                "Annualized Sharpe Ratio",
                                "Calmar Ratio"))
  tab.perf
  
  tab.risk <- table.Arbitrary(rets,
                              metrics=c(
                                "StdDev.annualized",
                                "maxDrawdown"
                              ),
                              metricsNames=c(
                                "Annualized StdDev",
                                "Max DrawDown"))
  
  tab.risk
  
  return (as.numeric(tail(final_acct$summary$End.Eq,1))-init_equity)

  #reset_quantstrat()
  
}
)
```

it appears to be parallized but it doesn't update init_equity correctly